# Id of a lambda expression in Python

Tags: python, function, lambda

As can bee seen below, In Python, I am assigning a lambda expression to the variable a, and also set the variable b equal to a. The identifiers of a and b are identical as expected. However, the id of a is different from that of the lambda expression itself. I don't understand why that is the case:

```
a = lambda x : x**3
b = a
print(id(a) == id(b))                    # prints True
print(id(lambda x : x**3) == id(a))      # prints False
```

I tried this with a regular function and the outcome was as expected:

```
def sq(x):
    return x**2

a = sq
print(id(a) == id(sq))    # prints True
```

Comment: This has nothing to do and is not specific to `lambda`, try to replace your lambda with `'hello world!'`, this is the same ;)

Comment: Typing `lambda: ...` again creates a completely new lambda object, even if it does the same thing. The unique lambda *object* has an id, not its textual representation.

Comment: How is your second example different from your first? You just forgot to redefine an identical function and test its identity against the original.